Invalid Nuget Package Version in CI/CD
We are getting the following error when trying to publish our package after successfully building it.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.204/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets(226,5): error NETSDK1018: Invalid NuGet version string: '1.0.0-06181390'. [/app_build/OurProject/OurSolution/OurSolution.csproj]

1.0.0-06181390 is our version which we are giving using /p:Version=$VERSION variable while building it and publishing it through GitLab pipeline. Basically, we are using the CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA at the end of the version, like 1.0.0-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA.
It was working fine until a couple of days ago, but now we are getting this. Any help on understanding why the sudden change might have occurred?

What was the last working version string? And how is it different from this one?

@Fildor, the same thing was working for us till a couple of days ago. We are basically using the CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA at the end. Like, 1.0.0-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

You currently use the commit hash as a pre-release indicator. According to the official SemVer documentation

A pre-release version MAY be denoted by appending a hyphen and a series of dot separated identifiers [...]. Numeric [pre-release] identifiers MUST NOT include leading zeroes.

The reason this has worked so far is that only a small amount of commit hashes (about 6%) start with a leading zero, and an even smaller amount (about 2% for shortened hashes) contain only numbers (no hexadecimal digits a-f). You basically just got very unlucky with your commit hash, hitting a chance of about 0.15%.
This means you have three basic options:

Decrease the likelihood of having no letters in the commit hash, by using the full 40 character commit hash CI_COMMIT_SHA instead of the shortened one. This reduces the probability of an invalid version to about 4 * 10-10 or about 1 in 2 billion.

Make your pre-release identifier non-numeric. Add some kind of identifier before or after your commit hash. It can even be separated by a hyphen, e.g. 1.0.0-sha-06181390 or 1.0.0-06181390-git

Actually use correct semantic versioning. According to SemVer

Build metadata MAY be denoted by appending a plus sign and a series of dot separated identifiers immediately following the patch or pre-release version.

So your version should actually look like this: 1.0.0+06181390


I would strongly suggest using the third option, as this is the only one that uses correct versioning.
